# Reset setTimeout after timer expires

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have an ongoing while loop. In the while loop, there is a `setTimeout()`. I want to reset the timer AFTER the timer expires. In other words, when timer expires, it should do some specified actions, and then freshly start the timer again.

For example, in the following code, `%%--Hi--%%` should be printed only ONCE in 5 seconds. However, after 5 seconds, `%%--Hi--%%` is printed continuously. I tried `clearTimeout` but it looks like that clearTimeout can stop timer only before timer expires.

```
while(){
    var timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function() {
                        console.log("%%--Hi--%%");
                        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
                        }, 
                        5000); //5 sec
}
```

Help please! Thanks!

Comment: It's not the timeout that's tripping you up, it's the infinite `while` loop. You're effectively creating thousands of timeouts every second.

Comment: But I need an infinite loop in order to keep reading a value from another device.

Comment: That doesn't mean that the creation of the timeout should be inside the infinite loop.

Comment: You're not creating one timeout every 5 seconds. You're continuously creating new ones. There's no need to clear the timeout. After expiring, it performs its action and then ceases to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the timeout that's tripping you up, it's the infinite `while` loop. You're effectively creating thousands of timeouts every second. Moving the timeout outside of the infinite loop should solve your problem.

```
function timedAction() {
    // your timed actions to be invoked every 5 seconds

    setTimeout(timedAction, 5000); // start the next timeout
}

setTimeout(timedAction, 5000); // start the first timeout

while() {
    // your continuously executing actions
}
```

There is no need to clear a timeout after it expires.

Alternatively you could also use `setInterval`, simplifying your code as follows:

```
function timedAction() {
    // your timed actions to be invoked every 5 seconds
}

setInterval(timedAction, 5000); // start the interval

while() {
    // your continuously executing actions
}
```

Comment: Oh.. setInterval..! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
logFun();

function logFun() {
    console.log("%%--Hi--%%");
    setTimeout(logFun, 5000);
}
```

or, you can try `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function () {
    console.log("%%--Hi--%%");
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout` method does not act like a sleep statement. Your `while` loop will continue to iterate continuously regardless of what time interval you set in the `setTimeout` method.

You should remove the `while` and simply use `setInterval()`. *(Mentioned in  [yibuyisheng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29738078/88204). +1)*

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    console.log("%%--Hi--%%");
}, 5000);
```

If you want to stop the interval, run the following:

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that setTimeout is an asynchronous function, so your code doesn't wait for it to finish before looping again. To get around this you have to create your new timer inside the previous timer.

Likewise you have to call any actions you want to execute from inside the timer and can't just call them from in the while loop, because they won't wait for the timer to finish.

```
function logFun() {
    console.log("%%--Hi--%%");
    // execute actions
    setTimeout(logFun, 5000);
}
```

This is what yibuyisheng has done with his answer that just showed up. (Still posting because the answer was not explained.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you must create the setTimeout() from the while loop, you could have a boolean (true/false) lock it. This is not as clean as yibuyisheng's answer, but it also allows you to add as much logic as you'd like to control enabling and disabling the timeout.

Example:

```
window.isTimeoutLocked = false;

while(true) {
   if (!window.isTimeoutLocked) {
     var myFunction = function () {
       console.log("%%--Hi--%%");
       //The timeout has fired. Unlock it for the next one.
       window.isTimeoutLocked = false;
     }
     window.setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);

     //Timeout is queued. Lock this code until the timeout fires.
     window.isTimeoutLocked = true;
   }
}
```

Also, I doubt that an infinite while loop is best for your upstream code. There is probably a callback that you can hook into, like requestAnimationFrame or some relevant event.